# Android Custom TextView to show Currency

Tags: android, textview, decimalformat

I need to set a mask for a textview to convert its text to a specific style (Currency, my own though Like this: Rls ###,###,###,### ) but I need to be able to get it's raw text later on. What shall I do?

======================================================

say I will pass this string to the TextView: `2120000`

It should be seen by user like : `Rls 2,120,000`

but the .getText method should return:  `2120000`

======================================================

the formatting code would be like this:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("Rls ###,###,###,###", symbols);
String prezzo = decimalFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(textTemp));
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way would be this:
To create a custom TextView as a Java Class

```
public class RialTextView extends TextView {

    String rawText;

    public RialTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public RialTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RialTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        rawText = text.toString();
        String prezzo = text.toString();
        try {

            DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###", symbols);
            prezzo = decimalFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(text.toString()));
        }catch (Exception e){}

        super.setText(prezzo, type);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getText() {

        return rawText;
    }
}
```

and in the XML instead of `<TextView` tag 
using something like this:

```
<com...RialTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:id="@+id/tv_itemgriditems_Price"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_itemgriditems_Remain"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
```

Comment: Check my answer, I have shared the same idea 15 minutes before your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your edittext in each time you enter an input character. Try this code snippet

```
EditText currencyEditText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("Rls ###,###,###,###", symbols);
        String prezzo = decimalFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(s));
        currencyEditText.setText(prezzo);
    } 

});
```

Comment: This would do the trick in showing the number to user, but wont help me when I want to get the raw number from .getText() method which returns `Rls 2,100,000` ... I need it to return `2100000`

Comment: When you want to get your raw number, just parse that data. replace coma with "" , thats it

Comment: You have to use your own modified method, there is no any built android library for this

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a class `MyParser`:

```
public class MyParser {

    //...
    public static String getRawValue(value) {
        //Converts value to raw value, for instance, converts Rls 2,120,000 to 2120000
    }

    public static String getViewValue(value) {
        //Converts value to view value, for instance, converts 2120000 to Rls 2,120,000
    }
    //...
}
```

Now, let's have another class, called `MyTextView`:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public CharSequence getText () {
        return MyParser.getRawValue(super.getText());
    }

    public void setText (CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type) {
        super.setText(MyParser.getViewValue(text), type)
    }

}
```

Comment: The idea is correct, but the complete answer is which I have posted,
Thanks though

Comment: I don't like your setText. setText should only deal with setting the text. You should call a method inside to resolve your String content. Imagine, if you want to reuse the same parsing algorithm, you will copy and paste the code elsewhere. You should have reusable solutions, so you should have something like the MyParser suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same DecimalFormat object that you used to format the string to parse it back the other way:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("Rls ###,###,###,###", symbols);

try {
    // get int value
    int i = decimalFormat.parse(textView.getText().toString()).intValue();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // handle error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for convert long to rial format

```
    public String FormatCost(long cost){
    try {
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###", symbols);
        return decimalFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(cost+""));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return cost + "";
    }
}
```