# TextView display amount in pattern

Tags: android

I have TextViev for display amount

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/amountText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="amount"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

How can I display amount in this TextView in `pattern="#,##0.00"`?

Comment: You need to extend `TextView`.
Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877167/android-custom-textview-to-show-currency)

Answer (score 0):

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(currency + " " +
                new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(amount));
spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.6f), 0, 1, 0);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

using SpannableString u can set it up for which ever pattern you want.

Comment: The main task - depending on the user's language, is to set a different display format for the sum

Comment: you can do it by setting different formats for different langugae, just u have to check which language the user has set and set the format

Comment: s this the only way to solve it? There are no other options? config xml for example?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
int x=1000;
DecimalFormat decimalFormat=new DecimalFormat("##,###");
textView.setText(decimalFormat.format(x));
```

Basically, you create a new decimal format and use it to format the text.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : **it is not recommended** to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes